# Generic type per record value in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, zod

I have an object like this:

```
import zod from 'zod';

const f1 = (params: { a: string }) => ({ b: params.a }); // some function
const f2 = () => {}; // some function

const dir = {
    // ok
    register: {
        method: f1, // some function
        inputSchema: zod.object({ a: zod.string() }),
        outputSchema: zod.object({ b: zod.string() })
    },
    // not ok
    view: {
        method: f2, // some function
        inputSchema: zod.object({ c: zod.string() }),
        outputSchema: zod.object({ d: zod.string() })
    }
};
```

Now, i want to enforce a type on the dictionary such that parameters of function in method should match `zod.infer<typeof inputSchema>` and return value of function should match `zod.infer<typeof outputSchema>`.

I tried the following, but typescript does not throw any error

```
const f1 = (params: { a: string }) => ({ b: params.a }); // some function
const f2 = () => {}; // some function

interface RecordValue<
    P extends zod.Schema = zod.Schema,
    Q extends zod.Schema = zod.Schema
> {
    method: (params: zod.infer<P>) => zod.infer<Q>;
    inputSchema: P;
    outputSchema: Q;
}

const d: { [key: string]: RecordValue } = {
    register: {
        method: f1, // some function
        inputSchema: zod.object({ a: zod.string() }),
        outputSchema: zod.object({ b: zod.string() })
    },
    view: {
        method: f2, // some function
        inputSchema: zod.object({ c: zod.string() }),
        outputSchema: zod.object({ d: zod.string() })
    }
};
```

How to enforce types like this?

Comment: `const d: { [key: string]: RecordValue } = {...}` may not be the entire problem but it's highly suspicious code. `RecordValue` is generic with defaulted type arguments but the defaults will always be used of the annotation on `d`. There may be other problems, but using unnecessary type annotations such as `d`'s is something typescript programmers need to stop doing. You are reducing the type safety of your by annotating. Type inference is important

Comment: @Atharva are you looking for `satisfies`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make a function to check the type, bu inferring the value type and interserting it with the correct type: https://tsplay.dev/N5x2Pw

```
function EnsureCorrect<
  K extends string,
  const R extends Record<K, RecordValue>
>(v: R & {
  [K in keyof R]: RecordValue<R[K]['inputSchema'], R[K]['outputSchema']>
}): asserts v is R { }

const d = EnsureCorrect({
  register: {
    method: f1, // some function
    inputSchema: zod.object({ a: zod.string() }),
    outputSchema: zod.object({ b: zod.string() })
  },
  view: {
    method: f2, // some function
    // ^!
    // Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(() => void) & ((params: { c: string; }) => { d: string; })'.
    inputSchema: zod.object({ c: zod.string() }),
    outputSchema: zod.object({ d: zod.string() })
  }
});
``
```

Comment: This is brilliant! 
Just a small change is needed, EnsureCorrect is not returning the value passed to it. Also, `asserts v is R` looks redundant. 
I've modified the [code](https://tsplay.dev/mpxLpm) little bit. Please let me know if it is correct.

Comment: One more doubt, can we enforce strict types on function parameters? E.g. Passing function with no parameters for `inputSchema` expecting some parameters is throwing no error.

Comment: @Atharva If you can call a function as `f()`, that means you can call it as `f(any)` just fine, that's just a way Javascrit works. Unleast you provide is a function of type `({notAna: whatever})=>whatever` or `(/*whatever*/) => {/*b is not a string*/}` it'll be fine, othervise it'sll error.